# Making a join with a referenced table with Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and I'm having a problem in making a join between two tables using Entity Framework.

In this case I have a query that is working:

```
        return db.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS
            .Where(genericIngredient => genericIngredient.STATUS_CODE_ID == enabledId)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(genericIngredient => GenericIngredientToViewModelWithUnitLabel(genericIngredient, languageId))
            .OrderBy(genericIngredient => genericIngredient.Name);
```

But I need to make a join with the table db.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS.INGREDIENTS and then apply a filter to the CAN_BE_USED attribute. I tried in many ways to do this but I'm having problems with this. I think the query that I made closer to what I want is the following:

```
        return db.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS
        .Where(genericIngredient => genericIngredient.STATUS_CODE_ID == enabledId)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(genericIngredient => GenericIngredientToViewModelWithUnitLabel(genericIngredient, languageId))
        .Join(db.INGREDIENTS,
            gi => gi.Id,
            i => i.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
            (i, gi) => new { GENERIC_INGREDIENTS = gi, INGREDIENTS = i })
        .OrderBy(genericIngredient => genericIngredient.Name)
```

The GenericIngredientToViewModelWithUnitLabel is the following:

```
    public GenericIngredientsViewModel GenericIngredientToViewModelWithUnitLabel(GENERIC_INGREDIENTS genericIngredient, int languageId = 0)
    {
        DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
        var genericIngredientTranslation = ReadGenericIngredientsTranslation(genericIngredient, languageId);
        var unitLabelTranslation = UnitLabelsService.Service.ReadUnitLabelTranslationById(db, genericIngredient.UNIT_LABEL_ID, languageId);
        return new GenericIngredientsViewModel
        {
            Id = genericIngredient.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
            StatusCodeId = genericIngredient.STATUS_CODE_ID,
            UnitLabelId = genericIngredient.UNIT_LABEL_ID,
            Name = genericIngredientTranslation.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_NAME + " (" + unitLabelTranslation.Name+ ")",
            Description = genericIngredientTranslation.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_DESCRIPTION,
            Languages = genericIngredient.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS_TRANSLATIONS.Select(translation => translation.LANGUAGE_ID).ToList()
        };
    }
```

In this second query it returns an error "anonymous type: INGREDIENTS GENERIC_INGREDIENTS, GenericIngredientsViewModel does not contain a definition for name.". This don't make many sense for me since the GenericIngredientToViewModelWithUnitLabel return the Name. This query must return an IEnumerable.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify the last line to retrieve the name correctly:

```
return db.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS
    .Where(genericIngredient => genericIngredient.STATUS_CODE_ID == enabledId)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(genericIngredient => GenericIngredientToViewModelWithUnitLabel(genericIngredient, languageId))
    .Join(db.INGREDIENTS,
        gi => gi.Id,
        i => i.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
        (i, gi) => new { GENERIC_INGREDIENTS = gi, INGREDIENTS = i })
    .OrderBy(output => output.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS.Name)
```

Comment: @DanielSerrão Does the existing query that you've mentioned above work? If it does, then as per the query `.Name` is what you are ordering by at the end and it is a property of your `GenericIngredientsViewModel` class. As per your error text, it looks like the last order by clause isn't able to access `.Name` property because the newly created anonymous type doesn't have it so the above answer should work. Can you try omitting the `OrderBy` clause to confirm if the error is due to it? Also if possible share the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of not recognizing the Name I just needed to change:

```
    gi => gi.Id,
    i => i.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
    (i, gi) => new { GENERIC_INGREDIENTS = gi, INGREDIENTS = i })
```

to

```
    gi => gi.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
    i => i.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
    (gi, i) => new { GENERIC_INGREDIENTS = gi, INGREDIENTS = i })
```

The problem was the order of the parameters and when doing "OrderBy(output => output.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS.Name)", I was in reality trying to fetch the Name from the INGREDIENTS which don't exist.

But now I have a problem where the result return many duplicates. The current query is the following:

```
        return db.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS
        .Join(db.INGREDIENTS,
            gi => gi.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
            i => i.GENERIC_INGREDIENT_ID,
            (gi, i) => new { GENERIC_INGREDIENTS = gi, INGREDIENTS = i })
        .Where(output => (output.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS.STATUS_CODE_ID == enabledId) 
                            && (output.INGREDIENTS.CAN_BE_USED == true)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(output => GenericIngredientToViewModelWithUnitLabel(output.GENERIC_INGREDIENTS, languageId))
        .OrderBy(genericIngredient => genericIngredient.Name);
```

This query don't have any error and return the right type IEnumerable but it return many duplicates. I tried the same query in SQL Server and it works perfectly :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The problem was that it existed many different ingredients for the same generic_ingredient. To solve that in SQL Server I need to use generic_ingredient_id "NOT IN" ingredients_ids. To make this using EF, we would probably need to use the "Contains". I didn't the final solution because I did it using a stored procedure.

Thanks for the help.